# What is the etymology of "-cade" as in motorcade or cavalcade?

Tags: etymology

What is the etymology for "Cade" as in motorcade or cavalcade? I guess it has a similar meaning in "cascade" as well.

I checked [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cavalcade&allowed_in_frame=0) "*but it didn't explain the etymology of "cade". Just that "in 20c. -cade came to be regarded as a suffix*"

Comment: Yes I did do that. but it didn't explain the etymology of "cade". Just that "in 20c. -cade came to be regarded as a suffix"

Comment: *cavalcade* comes from the past participle of *cavalcare* in Italian, just like *brocade* comes from the past tense of *broccare*.

Comment: @cobaltduck you answered in the comments while I was answering in the Answers. If you'd like to post it as an answer I will delete mine.

Comment: I don’t understand your edit. You say Etymonline didn’t explain the etymology of _-cade_, and then you quote the etymology of _-cade_ immediately afterwards. What is it about “in 20c. _-cade_ came to be regarded as a suffix” is it that you find unsatisfactory? That _is_ the etymology of the suffix.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I think the real question here is why the Italian pp suffix -ata, ato, is made into English -cade.

Comment: @Josh Well, it’s not really. It’s _-ata_ that was borrowed from Italian into Old French—or perhaps Middle French; can’t remember the exact order of things offhand—and then regularly became _-ade_ there. English just borrowed the French word. (Of course, if it had been the inherited French word, it would probably have ended up as _chevaucée_ or something like that instead…)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - from what Etymonline says, it was the French (1590) that borrowed from the Italian "cavalcata". So it is the result of an Anglicised   French loan word . Clear!!!

Comment: Correcting myself: the inherited French word is [_chevauchée_](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/chevauchée)… which is seemingly [also a word in English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chevauchee#English). The _d_ in the Old French form is perhaps due to Provençal influence. Looking a bit closer, there doesn’t seem to be a simple way to get from an Italian /t/ to a French /d/, even in a borrowing—it should either have remained or become /ð/ (which would then later be lost). It was also spelt _cavalcate_ in 15th- and 16th-century French, presumably straight from Italian.

Comment: @Janus: If you look at the etymology for [*brocade*,](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=brocade) it went from Italian *broccato* to Spanish *brocado* (where it lost the extra *c* and the *t* became *d*) to English *brocade*. So maybe *cavalcade* took a side trip through Spanish as well.

Comment: Josh yes that's question I meant. yes, Janus that's the insight I was looking to understand. thanks.

Comment: @PeterShor, in Spanish it's *cabalgata*, so this time Spanish is probably not to blame.

Comment: @Peter Taylor: Isn't it also *cabalgada*, with a /d/, in Spanish?  And the real question is: what was it in 16th century Spanish?

Comment: @PeterShor, that has a different (more military) meaning ,but I concede that my argument is significantly weakened. Covarrubias' *Tesoro de la Lengua Castellana* doesn't have either, unhelpfully.

Answer (score 22):

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cavalcade) sources *cavalcade* as a single word, part of which became a suffix.

> **cavalcade** (n.) 1590s, via Middle French *cavalcade* (15c.), [...] from
>   Latin *caballus* (see *cavalier*). Literally, “a procession on horseback;”
>   in 20c. *-cade* came to be regarded as a suffix and taken to form
>   *motorcade* (1913), etc.

*Cavalcade* is the source of the suffix.

Similar to the way *-gate* (from *Watergate*) became a suffix meaning “scandal about” (subject specified by the word to which it is attached), *-cade* came to mean “a procession of” (subject specified by the word to which it is attached).

There is no standalone traceable meaning to the suffix beyond “it was part of a word that meant something similar” now available to affix in other contexts.

Comment: Don’t forget to add links to your sources—I’ve added one in for you here.

Comment: The OED agrees with you here. "-cade, suffix.
   Taken by a false division of caval)cade n. and used in
various Combs., as aquacade, motorcade, etc., in the sense
'a procession, a show'.  Chiefly U.S."

Comment: Of course, "-ade" has already been abused to death in the English language, so at least "-cade" provides some clarity, even if it is a false division.

Comment: So in other words, this is exactly like what has happened with -gate being used to label most political scandals since the incident at the Watergate Hotel.

Comment: @Stuporman: You're referring to Gategate

Comment: Now I really want a journalist to describe a procession of scandal after scandal as a "gatecade".

Comment: @BoundaryImposition You mean [the Watergategate scandal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vB9JgxhXW5w)?

Answer (score 9):

The latin verb ending *-[icare](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ico#Latin)* forms verbs from nouns. So from the (late, vulgar) latin word *caballus* one get *[caballicare](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/caballicare#Latin)* directly translated that means "to 'horse'", which is how a late latin speaker would say "to ride a horse"

Digging deeper, the *[ic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-icus#Latin)* of *icare* is from the noun ending *i* and a suffix that forms adjectives *-cus*, the *-[are](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-are#Latin)* of *-icare* is the usual present infinitive verbal ending of latin verbs which end in -o.

In Italian, *-[icare](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-icare)* is still used to form verbs from nouns, for example *neve* (snow) gives *nevicare* (to snow).

From here the etymology dictionary gives details. From vulgar Latin *caballicare* the Italians got *cavalcare* (by regular sound shifts) which is gives a noun *cavalcata*. That became *cavalcade* in French, which was borrowed in English in the late 16th century.

All in all it is a bit of a mishmash. The "c" of cade is a fragment of one latin suffix, and the "ade" is a change pronunciation of the latin verbal ending "-are"

Comment: Nice. Explains both the caval- and -cade parts.

Comment: I thought the noun came from [*cavalcato*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cavalcato)/[*cavalcata,*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cavalcata) which is the past participle of *cavalcare* in Italian. So the *ade* came from a change of verb form, as well as a change of pronunciation.

Answer (score 2):

***[-cade](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cade)*** is a suffix *abstracted from [caval**cade**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cavalcade&allowed_in_frame=0)*:

> a combining form extracted from cavalcade, ***used with the meaning “procession” in the formation of compound words:***
>
> - *[motorcade](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=motorcade) (1909); tractorcade*; [autocade](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=autocade&allowed_in_frame=0)(1922); [acquacade](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=aquacade&allowed_in_frame=0)(1937).

(Dictionary.com)(Etymonline)